# character encoding of fortran unformatted files?

Tags: python, character-encoding

I am reading in a fortran unformatted file. If I use Python to read them in,

```
import struct
f = open(filename,'r')
values = struct.unpack('%20s',f.read(20))
```

I get characters like

\xf8, \xbf, \xad, \xe8, \xd8, \xec, \xd5, \x10, \xfd, \xbf

and so on. Each of these are of length one and string replacement functions do not work on them.

What character set am I dealing with?

**Edit**

pasting partial output of `f.read()`:

```
\xdf\xde#\xc0|\x18B\x9f\xec\xd6!\xc0]\x0b\x08b\xb1k#\xc0R#g}\xae\x14\xe8?\xde\x1c\x84b\x07S\xe8?.\x0b\x15\x07\xae\x99\xc5\xbf\xac\x9c\xa4\xf0\x8aV\xe4?K\t\x8a(3/\x07@\x97]rW\x8e?\x0b@\xe8\xfe\x9f0\x92P\x04@\xc6&\x98-VV\x07@\xa2\x8e\x86\xa8\xf2-\x18@N\xca\xa6\xc9\xe3W\x1b@\x1f\x96\x0f\xb2\nH\x18@\xc31Jv\xf8\x98\x18@\xacOBu\xcf\xd6'@A\xf0\x9fJ\x84{(@\x1d`.N\x9b\x15'@4\xa5\xb2\x91)\xd3'@\x851\x9d\x83\x98\x00\x02\xc0\xa2Iy\x1b\xca\xf2\x04\xc0eu\rt\xb2\xd5\x04\xc0V\x92\xaf\x9f\xf6\xbd\x02\xc0:\r\xfc\xc6\xf8\xfb\xae\xbf!\x95QZ\xcdx\xe7\xbf\x8e\xd9O\xdf\xd1\xc0\xe4?\xbe\xba\xae\xa5\xb3\x9e\xac\xbfJ0h('=\xf0?\x83\xd67\xcf\n4\xe0?$\xf9\x0c\x00\x05\xe5\xfc?\x97+c\x9d\xd1\xf0?V\xfc\xc8\xe4\x12\x98\xf3?m\x8aa\xc4\xe5}\xf8?s\x9b\xb4{\xf22\x00@\xc3t'\xd0-\xdc\xf5?\xf9\x8eb&Y\x7f\x0c\xc0\x8c\x91\xa7\xe2\xf0|\x0c\xc0d\xd3b\x1a_\x05\x06\xc0u\xa7\x9b\x8e\xcc\xaa\x0b\xc0\xe7\x8a0CG+\x0f\xc0s\x10\x07\x8f
```

Comment: What has this got to do with Fortran? This is purely a python issue.

Comment: Yes, but indicating that they are generated by Fortran may narrow down the possibilities?

Comment: I think we're going to need to see a chunk of the actual file.

Comment: Is a character written in language A different from that same character written in language B? How? Anyways, could you paste some of that file in here? Or on some paste site?

Comment: You should link to your other question that contains more information about what you are doing.

Comment: Are you sure you're dealing with a character set at all? Do you have any documentation about the format? What is the file normally used for? What is this Fortran program normally used for?

Comment: Thanks all! Sorry, I can't seem to copy-paste from the text file I am opening in emacs -- only a blank space is pasted. The program simulates the trajectory of molecules -- I should probably email the developer of the simulation software. I thought specifying "fortran unformatted" files would be specific enough for people who know about these things...

Comment: @crippledlambda: paste something like the output of `f.read()`.

Comment: Do you really have strings packed in unformatted file? Because if you packed an array of floats you have to unpack it as an array of floats; in other case you get strange symbols as in your example.

Comment: And use `b` in the `open` flags.

Comment: `od -c` is very good for hex dumps.

Comment: `xxd` is good too. Better, in my opinion.

Comment: @chris-morgan, thanks - that should have been obvious to me.

Comment: @andrey-sobolev: yes, I am not sure but the output is produced with something like `write(filenum) (xxx(i),i = 1,imax)` and so on.

Comment: It's certainly not any ASCII compatible encoding and it's not EBCDIC either, I tested it.  It's also not valid UTF-16 because the first two bytes would correspond to surrogate pairs.  It is also not `hz` encoded.  I think it's compressed, scrambled, or damaged.

Comment: @wberry: thanks so much! That is good to know. I got a separate reader program (in fortran) from a colleague; now trying to figure this out... (which is almost as cryptic as the output) Thank you.

Comment: Why didn't you show the `write` statement before?? What Fortran data type is the array xxx?  If it is integer or real, you are dealing with binary numbers, not characters.  That's what unformatted means.

Comment: @NedDeily, The array is defined by `real(8), allocatable :: xxx(:)`. So sorry, 99.9999% of the data I've worked with have been in ASCII so I was not even sure where to begin. A set of instructions informed me that the unformatted option produces a text file, which is why I thought it would be character. But yes, now I know it is binary. But I was able to compile and use the external reader... I guess the correct number of bytes have to be read in sequence in this case (and allocated to the correct data type), so I guess it was unwise of me to attempt this deciphering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any information on how the file was written, i.e. what Fortran `write` statements were used?  If not, you'll just be guessing.  Keep in mind that unformatted records normally contain binary data, such as integers or floating point numbers, and normally not encoded character data.  My guess is you are looking at binary integers.  Also you should be opening the file in Python as a binary file (`'rb'`).  That makes a difference on platforms like Windows.

Update: Now that you have disclosed that the data is type `real(8), allocatable :: xxx(:)` and was written with:

```
write(filenum) (xxx(i),i = 1,imax)
```

it's clear that the data is binary and not encoded characters.